# matplotlib weird vertical lines plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, charts

So I'm trying to plot my data and the last time I plot everything was fine, I want to have this type of graph [image: normal graph]
but my last csv file doesn't work and is giving me this type of graph : [image: my wierd graph]

I'm working with `pandas` to treat the data and `matplotlib` to draw it.

I've tried to change the size of the file, like with less rows and with a bigger screen because my first file was about 19 hours of data that I cut in Excel.

I checked and there's no pattern in the data to explain this, I can even draw a nice graph with Excel.

This is what my code looks like :

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np

%matplotlib qt
plt.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 0.9

# Obtenez le répertoire du fichier en cours d'exécution
repertoire_script = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# Définissez ce répertoire comme répertoire de travail
os.chdir('G:\Mon Drive\Fac\COOL_PLANTS\Exp\Flux\ ')

# Replace 'your_file_path/Data_test.csv' with the actual path to your CSV file
file_path = "GL840_01_2024-02-14_13-00-37_Converted.csv" #haricots sans tables pas arrosés
file_path ='GL840_01_2024-03-12_09-59-51.csv' #haricots table arrosés à 35cm
file_path ="GL840_01_2024-03-12_12-33-15.csv" #dralon table à 28cm
file_path ="GL840_01_2024-03-12_14-53-29.csv" #polyester recto verso noir table à 27cm
file_path ="GL840_01_2024-03-13_09-34-12.csv" #polyester recto gris dessous verso noir dessus table à 27 cm

file_path="test.csv"
nom_echantillon = ["haricots sans tables pas arrosés","haricots arrosés table à 35cm","dralon table à 28cm", "polyester recto verso noir table à 27cm", "polyester recto gris dessous verso noir dessus table à 27 cm"]
numero_echantillon = 4

# Specify the number of rows to skip (assuming 1 for the header)
header_rows = 30

# Read the CSV file into a DataFrame, skipping the header
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='\s*,\s*', engine='python', skiprows=header_rows)


# Convertir la colonne "Time" en format datetime
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
# Créer une nouvelle colonne pour la durée écoulée depuis le début de l'expérience
df['Elapsed_Time'] = df['Time'] - df['Time'].min()
# Convertir la durée écoulée en secondes
df['Elapsed_Time'] = df['Elapsed_Time'].dt.total_seconds()

# Afficher les premières lignes du DataFrame après conversion
print(df.head())


#%% Temp graph

# Créez une figure et un axe pour le graphique de ax1
plt.figure()
plt.plot(df['Elapsed_Time'], df["degC"], label="Table Total=T°C")
plt.plot(df['Elapsed_Time'], df["degC.1"], label="Table Rad=T°C")
plt.plot(df['Elapsed_Time'], df["degC.2"], label="Dessous Total=T°C")
plt.plot(df['Elapsed_Time'], df["degC.3"], label="Dessous Rad=T°C")
plt.plot(df['Elapsed_Time'], df["degC.4"], label="Dessus Total=T°C")

plt.grid()
plt.xlabel("Durée écoulée (secondes)")
plt.ylabel("Température (°C)")
plt.title("Graphique des températures "+nom_echantillon[numero_echantillon])
plt.legend()
plt.xlim(df['Elapsed_Time'].min(), df['Elapsed_Time'].max())
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

My data seems to look fine :

```py
df.head().to_dict()
Out[43]: 
{'NO.': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
 'Time': {0: Timestamp('2024-03-12 09:59:53'),
  1: Timestamp('2024-03-12 09:59:53'),
  2: Timestamp('2024-03-12 09:59:53'),
  3: Timestamp('2024-03-12 09:59:53'),
  4: Timestamp('2024-03-12 09:59:53')},
 'ms': {0: 0, 1: 200, 2: 400, 3: 600, 4: 800},
 'degC': {0: 22.05, 1: 22.05, 2: 22.05, 3: 22.05, 4: 22.05},
 'degC.1': {0: 22.41, 1: 22.42, 2: 22.41, 3: 22.42, 4: 22.42},
 'degC.2': {0: 23.21, 1: 23.21, 2: 23.21, 3: 23.21, 4: 23.21},
 'degC.3': {0: 22.97, 1: 22.98, 2: 23.0, 3: 23.0, 4: 23.0},
 'degC.4': {0: 23.16, 1: 23.16, 2: 23.16, 3: 23.16, 4: 23.16},
 'A1234567890': {0: 'LLLLLLLLLL',
  1: 'LLLLLLLLLL',
  2: 'LLLLLLLLLL',
  3: 'LLLLLLLLLL',
  4: 'LLLLLLLLLL'},
 'A1234567890.1': {0: 'LLLLLLLLLL',
  1: 'LLLLLLLLLL',
  2: 'LLLLLLLLLL',
  3: 'LLLLLLLLLL',
  4: 'LLLLLLLLLL'},
 'A123456789': {0: 'LLLLLLLLL',
  1: 'LLLLLLLLL',
  2: 'LLLLLLLLL',
  3: 'LLLLLLLLL',
  4: 'LLLLLLLLL'},
 'Elapsed_Time': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0}}
```

Sorry I've worked in French since it's my mother tongue but most of the data names are ok I guess...

Comment: You seem to have multiple y-values belonging to the same x. Matplotlib just connects the xy positions in the order of the input.  What do you want different?  You could consider seaborn's  `sns.pointplot(x=df['Elapsed_Time'], y=df["degC"])` which would connect the averages of the y-values (default it comes with an error bar). Please explain a bit more what you are expecting.

Comment: Ok so I've add the type of plot I wanted, @JohanC .

Comment: and some data @BigBen .  Thanks for your attention

Comment: As mentioned, you have multiple y-values for the same x value. All the x-values you provided are `0.0`.

Comment: Indeed i've noticed that, I think it's a problem of my data when I modified them with Excel, I deleted the seconds and put my graph all in minutes. Thanks for your time